# Soundcloud breaks entire website below the embed?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, soundcloud

I'm using Foundation on this website, I'm not sure if that's part of the issue, but I'm trying to embed Soundcloud into my client's website and it breaks the entire site that is below the embed! Any ideas why? I'm not sure what info you need other than this, let me know!

Here is the embed code:

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <iframe width="600px" height="600px" scrolling="yes" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/109522071&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true" class="soundcloud">
</div>
```

And below this I basically just have a footer, but it even cuts off some 
   < br > tags that I have. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in the closing `iframe` tag.

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <iframe width="600px" height="600px" scrolling="yes" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/109522071&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true" class="soundcloud"></iframe>
</div>
```